# Using structs with index to create vectors

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I came across a similar struct in a piece of code. while trying to use these I somehow got stuck. Here is what I wrote based on the structs I came across.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyStruct{
    unsigned char *ptr;
    int len;
}MyStruct;
typedef MyStruct *Vec_MyStruct;

struct MyGroup {
    int n_MyStruct;
    Vec_MyStruct myStructs;
};
typedef struct MyGroup MyGroup;
typedef struct MyGroup *Vec_MyGroup;

typedef struct MyBigGroup {
    int n_MyBigGroups;
    Vec_MyGroup myBigGroups;
}MyBigGroup;


int ArrayData();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("Started..\n");
    ArrayData();
    return 0;
}

int ArrayData()
{
    printf("ArrayData called..\n");
    MyStruct bb1;
    memset(&bb1,0,sizeof(bb1));
    bb1.ptr = (unsigned char *)malloc(6);
    bb1.len = 6;
    char *ch = "Hello";
    memcpy(bb1.ptr, ch, bb1.len);
    //      printf("1: ptr  %s\n", bb1.ptr);
    //      printf("1: len %d\n", bb1.len);

    MyStruct bb2;
    memset(&bb2,0,sizeof(bb2));
    bb2.ptr = (unsigned char *)malloc(6);
    bb2.len = 6;
    char *c = "World";
    memcpy(bb2.ptr, c, bb2.len);
    //      printf("2: ptr  %s\n", bb2.ptr);
    //      printf("2: len %d\n", bb2.len);


    Vec_MyStruct vec = malloc(sizeof(vec));

    vec[0] = bb1;
    vec[1] = bb2;
    printf("vec[0]: ptr  %s\n", vec[0].ptr);
    printf("vec[0]: len %d\n", vec[0].len);
    printf("vec[1]: ptr  %s\n", vec[1].ptr);
    printf("vec[1]: len %d\n", vec[1].len);
    //

    MyGroup perm;
    perm.n_MyStruct = 2;// 2 My_Struct vectors
    perm.myStructs = vec;
    printf("perm.myStructs[0].ptr: ptr  %s\n", perm.myStructs[0].ptr);
    printf("perm.myStructs[0].len: len %d\n", perm.myStructs[0].len);
    printf("perm.myStructs[1].ptr: ptr  %s\n", perm.myStructs[1].ptr);
    printf("perm.myStructs[1].len: len %d\n", perm.myStructs[1].len);

    MyBigGroup grp;
    grp.n_MyBigGroups = 1;
    grp.myBigGroups = &perm;


    printf("grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[0].ptr: ptr  %s\n", grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[0].ptr);
    printf("grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[0].len: len %d\n", grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[0].len);
    printf("grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[1].ptr: ptr  %s\n", grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[1].ptr);
    printf("grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[1].len: len %d\n", grp.myBigGroups[0].myStructs[1].len);
    return 0;
}
```

So MyGroup has a "list" of MyStruct items. It also has a variable that tells me how many MyStruct items exist. Vec_MyStuct just points to the MyStruct.
There is another grouping of the MyGroup  which is the MyBigGroup.
But what worries me here is although the code is working just fine, I am unsure if I am allocating memory correctly.Especially the MyBigGroup.. Or is there a more efficient way to use these structs to define multiple entries of MyStructs?

Thanks.

Comment: One suggestion: `Vec_` prefix for pointer typedefs is a rather unusual naming convention. First of all, a pointer is not a vector. Next, there *usually* isn't any reason even have a typedef for a pointer (the only time I've needed it is to pass it to a macro which accepts a type as a parameter, but only works with a single_word_typedef type). Even then, the most common convention I've seen it to prefix with `p` (i.e. something like `pMyGroup`). And note that you can typedef both symbols in [a single statement](https://pastebin.com/vshwxyxS): `typedef struct { int a; int b; } Group, *pGroup;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Vec_MyStruct vec = malloc(sizeof(vec));

vec[0] = bb1;
vec[1] = bb2;
```

This is wrong. You are allocating the size of a single pointer, then writing two structs into the memory. It should be `malloc(2 * sizeof(*vec))`.

Note that `typedef`ing a pointer is often [considered bad style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers), especially when the typedef has a confusing name such as `Vec_MyStruct`.

As far as I can see, the other parts of your code are correct, but some are somewhat error-prone. For example, the code that allocates the strings hard-codes the sizes. I'd make a function for filling the fields of a `MyStruct` which receives the string as a parameter, then uses `strlen` to determine its size.

Additionally, in `MyBigGroup`, you used a pointer to a local variable `grp.myBigGroups = &perm;`. This will work in this small example, but could lead to issues in larger code - the pointer won't be valid after the function exits, and if you try `free`ing the memory it will cause problems.

Comment: Ah.. yes, I seem to have allotted only for one vector! Thanks for pointing that out.  The hardcoded strings were just a quick example I cooked up to see and try to use those structs.

Comment: and why is it sizeof(*vec)?

Comment: @user907810 You didn't even allocate enough for one - you just allocated the size of a pointer. `vec` is a pointer and `*vec` is a struct. You want the size of two structs, so `2 * sizeof(*vec)`.

Comment: @user907810 Yes.